# Is there an inner product such that $T$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, diagonalization

Is there an inner product over $\Bbb C^2$ such that the linear transformation $T: \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ defined by the matrix 
 $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$
is normal in respect to it?

I tried to use the spectral thorem, and I found out that $T$ is not diagonalizable. Does that mean there is no such inner product?

Same goes over $\Bbb R$, and the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1  \\
        -1 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$ . In this case I found that there are no real eigen values, so same as before, is it true that there is no such inner product?

Comment: What is $T$? You did not define it.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question

Comment: The second $T$ is already normal with respect to the normal Euclidean inner product, since $T^* T = T T^* = 2I$.

Comment: You are right. So how come $T$ is not diagonalizable ? or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: For real normal operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces, in general an orthonormal basis can be found such that the corresponding matrix has diagonal blocks of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, or $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ - and is zero otherwise.  (You can prove this by finding a diagonalization of the complexification of the operator, and then examining what that means in terms of the original real operator.)

Comment: The key point for the first example is that diagonalizability does not depend on the inner product. More formally: if an operator $T$ isn't diagonalizable on the vector space $V$, it isn't diagonalizable on the inner product space $(V, \langle , \rangle)$ either, no matter the field of scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such inner product. If there was, it would follow from the spectral theorem that $T$ would be diagonalizable. This is about your first $T$.

Comment: Thank you. What about the second $T$ ?

Comment: The second one *is* normal as far as the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is concerned. Therefore, I do not understand your question.

Comment: It is true, but doesn't it contradict the spectral theorem that states $T$ is normal iff there is an orthonormal base of eigen vectors of $T$ ?

Comment: @user401516 No, because the spectral theorem only states that for *complex* matrices.